# Good way to run Java and Eclipse from a ramdisk

Tags: java, performance, eclipse, memory

It is often suggested to me that to improve the performance of the Eclipse development environment, that I should move the Java JDK/JVM (and possibly Eclipse) to a Ramdisk.

I know that the Ubuntu has this /dev/shm device always available, but whats the right way to set up a ram disk with Java on it that will be there everytime I boot up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across some articles the other day while investigating my own **/tmpfs** projects

Refer to:

http://prezi.com/xgwyp3reqanc/ubuntu-debian-ramdisk/

&

http://blog.normation.com/2010/07/27/set-up-eclipse-workspace-in-ram/

Comment: That first link looks exactly like what I am looking for thanks.  The second link recommends putting the Eclipse *workspace* files on the Ramdisk(!) which I am don't think I'll ever do!

Comment: Does this dramatically increase performance?