# Eclipse Indigo very slow on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse

hello fellow ubuntu users!

I have a really big problem with my Eclipse Indigo running on Kubuntu 12.04 32bit, Dell Vostro 3500, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M480 @ 2.67 (as `cat /proc/cpuinfo` said). It has 4GB RAM.

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` brings up the following:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5319.85
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5319.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5319.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x2
cpu MHz         : 1197.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 5319.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

`java -version` brings the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

it's the Oracle Java, not OpenJDK.

I try to develop an Android application for GoogleTV and Eclipse is this slow, that it can't follow my typing (extreme lagging!!), but this issue makes it almost impossible!

here is my `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

has anybody faced the same problems? can anybody help me on this problem? it's really urgent as I'm sitting here at my company and am not able to do anything productive...

Comment: Just a question, how large are the projects you are working on?  It's acceptably responsive for me on small projects.  Perhaps you could try breaking up projects in to smaller modules (I do get a bit of lag when switching from project to project), but it may help.

Comment: Are you maybe using the "Project Explorer" view with working sets as top-level elements? If so, that's maybe the problem. Either change the top-level elements to be projects or use the "Package Explorer" instead.

Comment: can you try it with java 1.6 and report the results plz?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same performance issues with eclipse on linux mint kde 13, I did some digging and it seemed that the default gtk theme oxygen was causing this. So I changed the theme to qtcurve and eclipse started to respond nicely. You might have to install qtcurve as it was not included in the kde desktop by default.

Comment: How did you change it to use qtcurve instead of oxygen as gtk theme?

Comment: You can change the theme under System Settings -> Application Appearance -> GTK+ Appearance

Comment: This answer works beautifully for me. To install qtcurve, just type 'sudo apt-get install qtcurve' in the terminal, put in your password, then change the settings in 'System Settings' as described above.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just eclipse that is slow. Do you think it is slower under Kde than under Unity?

I'm trying the following things out:

- http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/06/25/speed-up-your-eclipse-as-a-super-fast-ide/
- [Good way to run Java and Eclipse from a ramdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112996/good-way-to-run-java-and-eclipse-from-a-ramdisk)

Comment: This is wrong. It used to work very fast for me until I did the update. Conclusion... some gnome gtk libraries are causing that.

Comment: @danizmax Gee is that the thanks I get for trying to be helpful and giving a fast response. Why don't you provide a more useful answer, rather than down-voting anything that isn't a perfect match.

Comment: Sorry to upset you, I just down vote those answers that are really not true and can confuse others. Gee it's nothing personal xD

Comment: If it helps, as I already said, it stopped working for me when I updated Ubuntu, so it's either the kernel or some gtk library. Actually I'm searching for a solution right now, if I find one I'll post it here.

Comment: @danizmax I think it should be encouraged that people post as many different options as possible, let the best ones be upvoted. Yes downvote blatantly wrong/misleading stuff and it seems that is what you think of my answer, but I don't. The OP (@herom) didn't mention and upgrade/update so you can't assume that is when this started. Many things can make eclipse slow eg. Editing 3000+line java files, or plugin updates like projectlombok.org 0.11.2. I think a reasonable workaround when you don't know the real cause is running it from a ramdrive to get it super fast under the circumstances.